# Error trying to visualize data from neo4j using neovis.js

Tags: javascript, html, neo4j, neovis

I want to visualize the graph from my neo4j database like this using HTML [Graph in Neo4j](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WTHZ.png).

When I try to run this code

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title>DataViz</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #viz {
            width: 900px;
            height: 700px;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/neovis.js@2.0.2/dist/neovis-without-dependencies.js"></script>
</head>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var viz;
    function draw() {
        var config = {
            container_id: "viz",
            server_url: "bolt://localhost", 
            server_user: "neo4j",
            server_password: "***",
            labels: {
               
            },
            relationships: {
                
            },
            initial_cypher: "MATCH p= (:Idea)-[:contains]->(:Keyphrase) RETURN p"
        }

        viz = new NeoVis.default(config);
        viz.render();
        
    }
</script>

<body onload="draw()">
    <div id="viz"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

I get [the following errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMG6F.png). I tried to follow this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0-1A7f8993M&t=317s&ab_channel=Neo4j but can't get it to work. I am very unexperienced with HTML and js so would very much appreciate some help with this simple example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working for me. The fixes are 1) location of Neovis.js  2) and change the config parameter names like serverUrl instead of server_url.

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>DataViz</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #viz {
            width: 900px;
            height: 700px;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/neo4j-contrib/neovis.js/master/dist/neovis.js"></script>
</head>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var viz;
    function draw() {
        var config = {
                containerId: "viz",
                neo4j: {
                    serverUrl: "bolt://localhost:7687",
                    serverUser: "neo4j",
                    serverPassword: "awesome_password"
                },
                labels: { 
                },
                relationships: { 
                },
                initialCypher: "MATCH p = (:Character)-[:INTERACTS]->(:Character) RETURN p LIMIT 10"
            };

        viz = new NeoVis.default(config);
        viz.render();
        
    }
</script>

<body onload="draw()">
    <div id="viz"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @jose_bacoy, do you know how I could display the node properties as well?

Comment: You need to fill-in the labels and relationships, you can find examples here: https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neovis.js/ (look at the bottom example)